# Set timer for ambient mode (android wear)

Tags: java, android

I am developing a watchface for android wear and have some trouble with the watch going into ambient mode to quickly.

I am aware of that I cannot turn off ambient mode programatically, but can I increase the time before it turns on?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get acknowledged when enter ambient? To be honest, did not figure out what you want.